# A declared array is giving me the "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" error

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Game.main(Game.java:12)

Ive tried searching and this apparently means that im trying to assign a value to a null during
" machines[0].setPayoutRate(35); "

When I try and debug the program the array of objects doesn't show up as three objects. Just one with the value of " SlotMachine[3] " which doesn't make much sense to me. Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    SlotMachine[] machines;
    machines = new SlotMachine[3];

    int cash = 0, totalPlays = 0;

    machines[0].setPayoutRate(35);
    machines[1].setPayoutRate(100);
    machines[2].setPayoutRate(10);

    machines[0].setPayoutAmount(30);
    machines[1].setPayoutAmount(60);
    machines[2].setPayoutAmount(11);

    System.out.println("How many quarters do you have?");
    cash = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("how many times has the first machine been played?");
    machines[0].settimesPlayed(userInput.nextInt());

    System.out
            .println("how many times has the second machine been played?");
    machines[1].settimesPlayed(userInput.nextInt());

    System.out.println("how many times has the third machine been played?");
    machines[2].settimesPlayed(userInput.nextInt());

    while (cash >= 1) {
        if (cash >= 1) {
            cash = machines[0].play();
            totalPlays++;
        }
        if (cash >= 1) {
            cash = machines[0].play();
            totalPlays++;
        }
        if (cash >= 1) {
            cash = machines[0].play();
            totalPlays++;
        }
    }
 System.out.println("You played: " + totalPlays + " times.");
  }
}
```

Main class is above^
Object class is below

```
public class SlotMachine {

private int timesPlayed;
private int payoutRate;
private int payoutAmount;

public SlotMachine(int timesPlayed, int payoutRate, int payoutAmount) {
    this.timesPlayed = timesPlayed;
    this.payoutRate = payoutRate;
    this.payoutAmount = payoutAmount;
}

public int getTimesPlayed() {
    return this.timesPlayed;
}

public void settimesPlayed(int timesPlayed) {
    this.timesPlayed = timesPlayed;
}

public int getPayoutRate() {
    return this.payoutRate;
}

public void setPayoutRate(int payoutRate) {
    this.payoutRate = payoutRate;
}

public int getPayoutAmount() {
    return this.payoutAmount;
}

public void setPayoutAmount(int payoutAmount) {
    this.payoutAmount = payoutAmount;
}

public int play() {
    int moneyExchange = 0;
    timesPlayed++;

    if (timesPlayed != payoutRate) {
        moneyExchange = -1;
    } else if (timesPlayed == payoutRate) {
        moneyExchange = payoutAmount;
        timesPlayed = 0;
    }

    return moneyExchange;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You declared your array of length `3`, but it's not assigned any new `SlotMachine`s, so all elements remain `null`, causing the `NullPointerException`.  Initialize your array elements.

```
machines = new SlotMachine[3];
machines[0] = new SlotMachine(0, 35, 30);
machines[1] = new SlotMachine(0, 100, 60);
machines[2] = new SlotMachine(0, 10, 11);
```

Then you can access them through the array.

Comment: SlotMachine class don't have any default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your array with a size of 3, the array is created with `null` for each slot.

Then, you try to call a method on `null`. This will return a `Null Pointer Exception`.

You need to add objects (in this case `SlotMachine`) in the array that can have  `setPayoutRate()` called on them.

For example, you can declare your array as follow:

Answer (score 0):

It's because your creating an instance of the array, but not of the objects it contains.

```
SlotMachine[] machines;
machines = new SlotMachine[3];
```

You need to add:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    machines[i] = new SlotMachine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `SlotMachine` objects to `machines` reference

```
machines = new SlotMachine[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < machines.length; i++) {

      int timesPlayed=000;
      int payoutRate=000;
      int payoutAmount=000;

      machines[i] = new SlotMachine(timesPlayed,payoutRate,payoutAmount);
  }
```